# Details from barcode values

Tags: android, barcode

I know this question is getting repeated but please bear me till last line. I want to get details of product from barcode. I have seen so many post on stackoverflow.com referring to 'Google API for shopping' but post of the pages are now refer to 'Not found'. I think they hace deprecated it.

So what can be the other alternatives for this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming to scan and read the information from a barcode to your app, then you should steer towards [this library by zxing.](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) Its pretty good for encoding and decoding most formats of barcodes. You will find plenty of documentation on how to set it up too.